# Why isn't Haskell able to optimize this? (Nothing gets propagated needlessly in the Maybe monad.)

Tags: haskell

Let's start with

```
boom :: Int -> Maybe a -> Maybe a
boom 0 x = x
boom n x = boom (n-1) (x >>= (\y -> Just y))
```

It's a simple function that just repeatedly shoves (`>>=`) a `Maybe` value into a trivial `\y -> Just y` function.

Now, the program

```
main = do
    let z = boom 10 (Nothing :: Maybe Int)
    putStrLn $ show z
```

runs very quickly, in a split second. However, the program

```
main = do
    let z = boom 10000000 (Nothing :: Maybe Int)
    putStrLn $ show z
```

takes a few seconds to finish, even if I compile with `ghc -O` (GHC 7.8.3).

This means that Haskell is not able to optimize this away. `Nothing` gets shoved repeatedly into a function even if there is no need for it to do so.

My question is, **why**? Why can't it deduce that a `Nothing` always ends up as `Nothing` in repeated shoving? In other words, **why isn't it able to immediately *short-circuit* at the first `Nothing`**?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the Monad instance or with Maybe. `x >>= (\y -> Just y)` = `x >>= Just` = `x >>= return` = `x` (according to the Monad laws). You can write `boom n x = boom (n-1) x` and you will get the same behaviour. You are explicitly doing recursion on the first arugement - the `Int` - it would be a very non-trivial optimization in general to deduce that a recursive function can be simplified to a non-recursive definition. You can do this optimization yourself: `boom n x = case (x >>= Just) of {Nothing  -> Nothing; y -> boom' (n-1) y}`

Comment: Some further investigation: GHC won't even recognize that if `boom :: Int -> a -> a; boom 0 x = x; boom n x = boom (n-1) x` then `boom n` is `id`. I'm not sure I can say _why_, but I don't think the bulk of the question about how to do this is actually about `Maybe` and short-circuiting.

Comment: What happens if you add ``x `seq` `` to the beginning of the second case?

Comment: @dfeuer Nothing interesting changes (it was one of the things I tested during my investigation). It gets a little bit faster -- but it doesn't switch over from a linear-time algorithm to a constant-time one.

Comment: When using -fllvm the expected optimization appears to take place...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yours is a nice example of a function which is slow *because it is tail recursive*. In strict languages, tail recursive functions are usually preferred since they typically lead to a better performance (in both time and space). In lazy ones tail recursion is not so beneficial. Indeed, a non tail recursive variant of your function is:

```
boom :: Int -> Maybe a -> Maybe a
boom 0 x = x
boom n x = x >>= (\y -> boom (n-1) (Just y))
```

The above will still loop `n` times when `x` is a `Just something`. However, it will do that in *constant space* unlike the original code which builds a large thunk in its second argument. Even better, when `x` is `Nothing`, the the above code will return immediately.

I do realize that this does not really answer your question about "why" GHC is not able to optimize this. But hopefully, it can show that these kinds of optimizations are quite subtle, and often involve an inductive reasoning. Expecting the compiler to optimize this is probably asking a bit too much.

Answer (score 1):

you need to force the recompile with `-fforce-recomp`

compiled with `ghc` and got 1.44s

compiled with `ghc -O` and got 1.44s

compiled with `ghc -O -fforce-recomp` and got 0.00s to 0.04s

note

It still does not work with `boom maxBound (Nothing :: Maybe Int)`

You will be waiting a very long time.

Comment: Indeed I can reproduce this behavior (somewhat) on my system: `ghc = 1.961sec`, `ghc -O2 = the same` - using `-fforce-recomp = 0.218sec` so I think that is the reason of why the LLVM backend might suddenly produce better behavior as Thomas mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

Because `boom` expands the `n-1` first.

So `boom 100 x` = `boom (100-1) ...` = `boom (100-1-1) ...` etc ...

You can try swapping the argument of boom (but I'm not sure that will change anything).

Comment: In my tests, `print (last [0..n :: Int])` takes about 85% of the time of `boom n Nothing`. So just counting up to an appropriately big number does seem to be a large chunk of the time -- but there is also a chunk of time left over spent thinking about the `Maybe` bit. And this doesn't really answer the actual question, which is: why doesn't GHC recognize that `boom n` is `id`?

Comment: Ghc doesn't recognise that boom is id because it's not : boom -1 will loop (I'd won't)

Comment: `boom (-1)` will loop, but not forever (try `(minBound :: Int) - 1 == maxBound` in ghci). And even if that weren't so, one might hope that you could determine that `boom n` was `id` whenever `n >= 0`.